# Is OpenCV findFundamentalMat apply normalization before calculation

Tags: c++, opencv

As far as I know it is better to normalize 2D key-points before calculation of Fundamental matrix.

The Matlab version of this function is available on http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/Projective/normalise2dpts.m

The question is, if OpenCV findFundamentalMat apply normalization before calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering about this as well, so I decided to check.  Debugging into the implementation of version 2.4.9, I found that:

If you're using the CV_FM_RANSAC method, it was using the 7 point algorithm without performing any normalization.

File:  fundam.cpp  around line 350

If you specify  CV_FM_8POINT, then it estimates and applies scaling.  This however, uses all matches, including outliers

File: fundam.cpp around line 490